The radius of convergence using root test
Is the root test sufficient for finding the radius of convergence of any power series ,i.e, does it determine the whole area where a power series converges? if the answer is no can you give an example where this does not hold?

The root test determines the radius of convergence.
For the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$, we have
radius of convergence $R$, where
$$
\frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{k \to \infty} |a_k|^{1/k} .
$$
This uses convention $1/\infty = 0$ and $1/0 = \infty$.

However, this does not tell us the exact set of convergence ... For example
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}z^k$ yields radius of convergence $1$, but we still must determine convergence at $z=-1$ and divergence at $z=1$.  If $z$ is a complex variable we have infinitely many points with $|z|=1$ where the radius of convergence does not tell us about convergence.
